# When does a boyfriend or girlfriend become a tenant?

Tags: landlord, nevada

My roommate's boyfriend spends more nights here at our shared apartment than I do. His dog is here full time in violation of the lease that says `no pets`. He has the key code and comes and goes as he pleases to my dismay even when she is not home. Our lease states that `the premises are to be used as a private residence for Tenant(s) listed in Clause 1`. He is obviously not on that list.

- When does he need to be on the lease?
- When should he start paying rent?
- Is there anything I can do to prevent him from living here?
- Should he be able to come and go as he pleases without her?
- Is there anything that I can add to a lease to avoid this in the future?

Comment: Check to see if there's a clause about guests.  Also, if there's a building association, it may publish rules about guests that don't appear in your contract explicitly but are nonetheless incorporated via indirect language in your contract.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When does he need to be on the lease

When he becomes a tenant instead of a guest, always assuming that the landlord is willing to have him as a tenant.

> When should he start paying rent?

Ditto

> Is there anything I can do to prevent him from living here?

Unless the lease or the body corporate places limitations on houseguests, no. Your co-tenant is entitled to quiet enjoyment of her rights as a resident: normally these would include the right to have houseguests. Of course, she must not infringe your rights to quiet enjoyment.

> Should he be able to come and go as he pleases without her?

Legally, if she has given him permission then that's fine.

> Is there anything that I can add to a lease to avoid this in the future?

Provisions about houseguests.

What you have right now is a social problem, not a legal one. Social problems are best sorted out by talking to one another. Come to think of it: so a legal problems.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What if he threatened me with violence when I tried to talk to him? Eh, may be I'll post that as a separate question.